# Why is getThreadAllocatedBytes not consistent?

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I have this method threadAllocatedBytes() from a [JavaSpecialists newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue230.html) 
 that calls out to the class ManagementFactory

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.management.ObjectName;

public class MemoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            testMemory(i);
    }

    private static void testMemory(int nChars) {
        long bytes = threadAllocatedBytes();
        char[] test = new char[nChars];
        long bytes2 = threadAllocatedBytes();
        System.out.println("diff[" + +(nChars + 1) + "] = " + (bytes2 - bytes));
    }

    public static long threadAllocatedBytes() {
        try {
            return (Long) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
                    new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.THREAD_MXBEAN_NAME), "getThreadAllocatedBytes",
                    new Object[] { Thread.currentThread().getId() }, new String[] { long.class.getName() });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
```

The output of this program is ;

```
diff[1] = 1072
diff[2] = 1080
diff[3] = 1080
diff[4] = 1080
diff[5] = 1080
diff[6] = 1088
diff[7] = 1088
diff[8] = 28584
diff[9] = 1088
diff[10] = 1096
```

Why did the 8th run show a much higher allocation ?
What can I do to make it more consistent ?

Comment: Interstingly if the test is run with different sizes of `char[] test` e.g. `new char[nChars*10]`, ..., `new char[nChars*1000]`, I consistenly observe a jump in the 8-th allocation of about 26-28kb, independent of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs

> long getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)
>
> Returns an approximation of the total amount of memory, in bytes,
>   allocated in heap memory for the thread of the specified ID.

Comment: I wasn't complaining about it not being terribly accurate -- I was trying to understand it's behavior about the 8th run which is very outlier. How do we deal with it ?

Comment: I did not suggest you were complaining about accuracy. I was showing you the part in the manual where Sun/Oracle say don't worry about it. In order to understand further what is going on you wil have to dig down in to the vm to understand things like the garbage collector and how it is implemented in the vm yo uare using. Do not forget the gc is lazy so although you're thread may have released an object, the gc has not neccesaily cleaned it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to TLABs being used. To improve performance allocations are done in a Thread Local Allocation Buffer. This allows allocation to be very fast, simply bump a thread local pointer as part of reserving memory until the TLAB is full.

To keep performance good no allocation tracking is done when a Object fits in the TLAB, rather the memory is incremented as part of the TLAB being retired.

```
if (retire) {
  myThread()->incr_allocated_bytes(used_bytes());
}
```

So most likely you are using up a TLAB as part of the 8 iteration and thus see a big bump.